# How this code works ( assembly)

Tags: assembly

My teacher didn't explain so well, so I ask you why this code changes a character into hexadecimal?

```
proc convert  
  cmp DL, 9  
  jbe its_a_digit ;JUMP IF ( DL <= 9 )  
;its_a_letter:  IF NO JUMP, STAYS HERE  
  add dl, 55 ;CONVERT TO LETTER  
  jmp finish 

its_a_digit:    
  add dl, 48 ;CONVERT TO DIGIT  
finish:  
  ret  
endp
```

for example a-> 61 A->41 0->30

Comment: What is meant by "for example a-> 61 A->41 0->30"? The code shown will always convert a value of 10 through 15 in DL to the ASCII value of an upper case letter (A through F). If the input value is ten then 10 + 55 = 65 (41 hex) the ASCII value for A. To convert to lower case change 55 to 87.

Answer (score 2):

That code is just to convert the **number** from DL register in range of [0-15] to its **ASCII** code.

Compare input number from register DL with 9

```
cmp DL, 9
jbe its_a_digit ;JUMP IF ( DL <= 9 )
```

In case when input number is greater than 9, add ASCII code of 'A' symbol

```
add dl, 55 ;CONVERT TO LETTER
jmp finish
```

In case when input number is less or equal than 9, add ASCII code of '0' (zero) symbol

```
its_a_digit:
add dl, 48 ;CONVERT TO DIGIT
```

Comment: The range is 0–9, isn't it?